# SSL not working for certain sites on ubuntu 19.04 server

Tags: 19.04, python3, ssl, wget

So, on my new Ubuntu server I got recently, I cannot, for the life of me, get ssl to work with certain sites. I have tried adding their Root, Intermediate, and Client certificates to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` ([image](https://butts-are.cool/WinSCP_uPUVSN9G2Q.png)) to no avail. I've also tried reinstalling the `ca-certificates` package. I'm at a loss on what I need to do to get this fixed. I get the "Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority" error when using [wget](https://butts-are.cool/putty_nQfymvTTTY.png), and python (3.7). I'm not getting them in curl, or node. The host I'm using is [Contabo](https://contabo.com). This has been happening since day one of me having the server, nothing that changed recently. These are not my websites, I have nothing to do with them, the main one I've tried was https://discordapp.com, I get the ssl error in wget/python, but no error in curl/node.

Comment: Have you Generated a CSR code

Comment: It would be useful to know what these "certain sites" are exactly. If you don't want to tell check these sites with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and fix all the reported problems until you get an A rating or better.

Comment: These are not *my* sites, look at the link on [wget](https://butts-are.cool/putty_nQfymvTTTY.png), it's clearly a request to discordapp.com, I site I 100% have no affiliation with